# Distributed general load question related to mechanical engineering

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> The pressure loading on the plate is described by the function
>   $$\rho = 10 \left[ \frac{6}{x+1} + 8 \right] \; \mathrm{lb}/\mathrm{ft}^2.$$
>   Determine the magnitude of the resultant force and the coordinates $(\overline{x}, \overline{y})$ of the point where the line of action of the force  intersects the plate.
>   [image: This is the question.]

I was able to solve this question using a simple integration. However, I tried to solve it as a co-planar distributed load as the width of the surface is constant and the loading varies only by x. When i tried this, the answers I got were wrong. Could anyone explain to me If this can really be expressed as a co-planar load and what the conditions are for a general distributed load to be represented as a co-planar load.

Comment: FYI, putting questions into links or pictures is frowned upon here. In future, please typset all questions with MathJax (which I see from previous questions, you have started using). While the picture here is a helpful illustration as well as the problem statement, it is preferable if you insert a picture into the answer, rather than post a link.

Comment: You should add the tags of multivariable calculus.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I'm a relatively new user and still not very thorough with MathJax. But will follow your advice. I do need an explanation for the question though.

Answer (score 0):

No magic, just grind:

$F= \int_{x=0}^2 \int_{y=0}^3 p(x,y) dx dy = 3 \int_0^2 10({6 \over x+1}+8)dx= 60 (3 \ln 3 + 8)$.

$\bar{x} = {1 \over F} \int_{x=0}^2 \int_{y=0}^3 xp(x,y) dx dy = {1 \over F} 60(14-3 \ln 3)$

$\bar{y} = {1 \over F} \int_{x=0}^2 \int_{y=0}^3 y p(x,y) dx dy = {1 \over F} \int_0^3 y dy \int_0^2 10({6 \over x+1}+8)dx = {3 \over 2}$